# How to test if google analytics code works in angular 2?

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics. Am trying to implement Google analytics to my angular 2 project. I have implemented like below:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from "@angular/router";
import {GoogleAnalyticsEventsService} from "./google-analytics-events.service";
declare var ga:Function;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

   onSubmit = function(login){
      console.log(login);
    }
  constructor(public router: Router, public googleAnalyticsEventsService: GoogleAnalyticsEventsService) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
      }
    });
  }
    submitEvent() {
      this.googleAnalyticsEventsService.emitEvent("testCategory", "testAction", "testLabel", 10);
    }

  }
```

and google-analytics-events.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
declare var ga:Function;
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAnalyticsEventsService {

  public emitEvent(eventCategory: string,
               eventAction: string,
               eventLabel: string = null,
               eventValue: number = null) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: eventCategory,
      eventLabel: eventLabel,
      eventAction: eventAction,
      eventValue: eventValue
    });
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Can any one suggest me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new property in Google Analytics and copy the UA-ID into your index.html snippet at `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');`.

[Here](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-google-analytics-google-tag-manager/) you can read a good article about Angular and Google Analytics. Same as the author, I would highly recommend to use Google Tag Manager. But of course it's also possible without like you did.

Comment: yup thats easy, but am choosing [this](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-include-google-analytics-event-tracking/) one works.